# Angular2 - get properties key from JSON Schema to generate html template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, jsonschema

What am trying is to generate a Menu bar dynamically, for which I need read a JSON Schema, get its properties key and append to the html template, which in turn will get compiled and loaded in some another class.

Working first time with schema.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HtmlOutlet } from './html-outlet';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-home',
    template: `<html-outlet [html]="value"></html-outlet>`,
})
export class HomeComponent {

    menu = MENU;

    pros = new Array<string>();
    arrayofKeys = new Array<string>();
    arrayLabelKeys = new Array();
    value: string;

    constructor() {
        this.value = this.prepareMenuHtml();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let configObj = JSON.parse(`{
        "title": "Example Schema",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "MENU": {
                "type": "object"
            }, 
            "HOME": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ABOUT US": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "CONTACT": {
                "type": "string"
            },
        }
    }`);

        this.pros = configObj["properties"];
        this.arrayofKeys = Object.keys(this.pros);



/* this.arrayofKeys.forEach(key => {
                this.arrayLabelKeys.push(key);
                console.log(this.arrayLabelKeys);
            }) */


    this.value = this.prepareMenuHtml();

    }
```

> This prints all the properties key - like Menu, Home, About Us etc.

```
    prepareMenuHtml(): string {
        let Menu = '<div>';
            this.arrayofKeys.forEach(key => {
                 Menu += `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="#">${key}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>`;
            });
            Menu += '</div>';
        return Menu
    }
}
```

> What it should be like is each tab item should be separate list item, coz I need to append different favicons to different tabs, so I need something like :

```
  <li><a href="#">${key.something}</a></li>
```

or may be

```
  <li><a href="#">{{key.something}}</a></li> 

prepareMenuHtml(): string {
        let Menu = '<div>';
            this.arrayofKeys.forEach(key => {
                 Menu += `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>Menu</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">${key}</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">${key}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>`;
            });
            Menu += '</div>';
        return Menu
    }
}
```

Please guide me where am going wrong and how can I get the properties key and append to the specific position in the html template.

New to angular2 or angular itself, so do ignore if done silly mistakes in code or concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
prepareMenuHtml(): string {
   let Menu = '<div>';
   Menu += `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">`;
   this.arrayofKeys.forEach(key => {
      Menu += `<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${??glyphiconName??}"></span>${key}</a></li>`;
   });
   Menu += '</ul></div></nav></div>';
   return Menu;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, figured out how to pass the glyphiconName too on the same iteration..just created a extra tag in the json schema as "image" and replaced the values as you have suggested in the code.